# "master_not_discovered_exception" when trying to configure ElasticSearch and LogStash on EC2 Instance

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I have 2 ec2 instances with ELK deployed on each. I made the following changes to my elasticsearch.yaml file:

```
node.data : true
network.host : 0.0.0.0
discovery.seed_hosts : []
cluster.initial_master_nodes :  []
```

When I run `curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'` I get the expected output:

```
{
  "name" : "ip-10-0-0-89",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Lu5H6q6VSfia_pUq2cjg_w",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.17.6",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "f65e9d338dc1d07b642e14a27f338990148ee5b6",
    "build_date" : "2022-08-23T11:08:48.893373482Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.11.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I have logstash installed and configured, but when I run: `sudo curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&pretty'`, I get

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
        "reason" : null
      }
    ],
    "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
    "reason" : null
  },
  "status" : 503
}
```

The above configuration was working for me on the other ec2 instance, so I am curious as to why it isn't working on the new instance. Am i missing something?

Comment: can you share the whole elasticsearch.yml file ?

Comment: can you share the output of  "curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health'"